# Steward Platform Trigonometry - Solving for servo angle $θ$ in $(Y−S\cosθ·C)^2 + (X−S\cosθ·B)^2 + (Z−S\sinθ)^2 = L^2$

Tags: trigonometry

I am making steward platform and have done all the necessary trigonometry in order to complete the project. However, I have gotten an equation that I keep getting stuck on how to simplify it. In the following equation:

$$(Y−S\cosθ·C)^2 + (X−S\cosθ·B)^2 + (Z−S\sinθ)^2 = L^2$$

I expand it to

$$Y^2 - 2·Y·S·C\cosθ + (S·C\cosθ)^2 + X^2 - 2·X·S·B\cosθ + (S·B\cosθ)^2 + Z^2 - 2·Z·S\sinθ + (S\sinθ)^2 = L^2$$

After expanding it, I'm stuck on factoring the $\cosθ$ and $\sinθ$ onto one side of the equation so I can solve for $θ$. I tried factoring but, in that case, I keep getting stuck on the $\sin^2θ$ and how to separate it from the different trigonometric functions. I would like some help on the process to solve for this angle.

Thank you!

Comment: You have an eqn of the form $$Fc^2+Gc+Hs^2+Js+K=0$$ where $c:=\cos\theta$ and $s:=\sin\theta$. To move forward, convert sines to cosines. First, write $s^2=1-c^2$; then, to handle the remaining sine: isolate it, square everything, and substitute $s^2=1-c^2$ again:
$$Fc^2+Gc+H(1-c^2)+K=-Js \quad\to\quad (Fc^2+Gc+H(1-c^2)+K)^2= J^2(1-c^2)$$ This gives you a quartic equation in $c$. There *is* [a symbolic formula for the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), but it's *exceedingly* messy; numerical methods are typically recommended. ... Good luck!